# SQL Server 2005 Blob Data Hit-Highlighting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, ifilter, hit-highlighting

I have a table with a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column in which I am storing `.docx`, `.xlsx` and `.pdf` files. I have the iFilters installed for both Microsoft Office 2010 and Adobe. They are registered with SQL Server 2005 and the document types show up in this query:

```
select * from sys.fulltext_document_types
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to implement hit-highlighting for the BLOB data using a CLR procedure or something? I don't know where to start.

I know that SQL Server 2005 does not natively support hit-highlighting. I also know that there is a plugin out there that enables it: http://www.interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkhighlight/, however, I cannot use third party software, it must be a custom implementation.

Comment: [This article might be useful](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/hit-highlighting-in-full-text-search).

Comment: In that article, it looks like the are full text indexing the contents of the documents in a NVARCHAR(MAX) field. I need to be able to extract a summary from a document blob stored in VARBINARY(MAX)...not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I see, yeah, not sure then, sorry.